# php counter loop to out put 24 hours fill empty values

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop, counter

I have a sql result as:

```
    |date       |hour |count  |
    |2014-03-03 |20   |10     |
    |2014-03-03 |18   |9      |
```

I want to display the count for 24 hours, but when the count is 0, it doesn't display anything.
The output I would like to see is:

```
2014-03-03 | 00:00 | 0
2014-03-03 | 01:00 | 0
2014-03-03 | 02:00 | 9
.
.
.
2014-03-03 | 23:00 |23
```

Below is the PHP code that generates a table that displays the hourly count:

```
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($hourlycalls)) {
        $hourly = '0';
        foreach($hourlycalls as $val) {
            if($row[1] == $val['hour']) {
                $hourly = $val['count'];
                break;
            } 
        } 

        $result .="
            <tr><td align=center>".$row[0]."</td>
            <td align=center>".$row[1]."</td>
            <td align=center>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";

    }
```

I've tried to include a counter, but just can't get it to work.
Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your results in an array, whose index is the hour:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($hourlycalls)) {
    $results[$row[1]] = $row;
}
```

Then use an hourly loop to display the values from the query, or defaults for hours that weren't returned:

```
for ($hour = 0; $hour < 24; $hour++) {
    if (isset($results[$hour])) {
        $row = $results[$hour];
    } else {
        $row = array($date, $hour, 0);
    }
    $row[1] = sprintf("%02d:00", $row[1]);
    $result .= "
        <tr><td align=center>".$row[0]."</td>
        <td align=center>".$row[1]."</td>
        <td align=center>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";
}
```

BTW, I recommend you get out of the habit of using `mysql_fetch_row`, and use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead. Accessing returned values by column name makes the code much more readable.

Comment: :Thanks for your input! It loops indeed correct now, and outputs dates & times correctly, only now all counts are 0

Comment: I thought the query was returning times like `01:00`, not just `1`, so I was looking up in the array wrong. Try now.

Comment: One thing left it seems, the date gets displayed twice for the rows with count 0.

Comment: I don't see how that can be. I only put it once in the array.

Comment: Stripped it of like: `$row = array(substr($date, 0, -13), $hour, 0)`

Comment: I assumed `$date` would just contain the date.

Comment: Got it, there's another variable in rest of the script that holds a date range, that $date variable got displayed.

Comment: I just made up that variable, I assumed you would realize you need to fill it in with whatever you want displayed there.

Comment: Still learning of how to work with arrays. Bit confusing sometimes.